# How should I feed sturgeons during winter?

Tags: feeding, fish, pond, sturgeons

We currently have two sturgeons in our pond. I heard that they are active during winter and need to be fed.

How much do they need (in relation to their weight or number)? How often and at which time of the day should I feed them? Do I have to use different food than during summer?

Comment: That's so cool! I think your question is completely on-topic. Now for a completely off topic question - could you post some pictures?

Answer (score 8):

According to [What Sturgeons Want](http://www.sturgeon-web.co.uk/what-sturgeons-want), sturgeons need to be fed during winter or they will starve. Unfortunately, the amount they eat is trial-and-error: throw some pellets, wait until they eat, and track how long it took.  If they quickly, throw more pellets, etc.

Remember they are carnivores, so choose appropriate food; don't hope that they will eat plants during winter. :)

Comment: Uneaten food shouldn't remain in the pond because it will release phosphate (PO_4) into the water which is nurition for algae.